# getAttribute error in Kartograph.js

Tags: javascript, svg, kartograph

I want to use Kartograph.js for creating an interactive map. My code is as follows:

```
    var map = kartograph.map('#map');

    map.loadMap('map.svg', function(map) {
        map.addLayer('asia', { name: 'Asia' });
    });
```

Code for `map.svg` can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/069xEJKm

My problem is, that after initializing the map, all I'm getting is the error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`.

What can I do?

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370194/error-in-kartograph-js">click here</a> here is the same problem and its solution